# Mouse cursor not appearing as desired when using background process

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am running a long process as a background process as the process makes my UI unresponsive.

Now the issue is that, while the process is running as a background process, I want to display a wait cursor. I tried using dispatcher to update the cursor, but it does not work.

My process runs on button click:

```
private void btnStartAsyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundworkerprocess.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In the backgroundworkerprocess event:

```
void backgroundworkerprocess_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.dispatcher.invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new action((delegate) {
            this.cursor = cursors.wait
        })
    );
}
```

I was hoping this would cause a wait cursor to be displayed anywhere on the form, but it's only showing up when the mouse is over the button.

Comment: That's not even valid C#. You have missing semicolons and incorrect capitalization. What's your *actual* code?

Comment: Well, you're not setting the cursor. Starting the BackgroundWorker won't automatically change the cursor. You have to change the Button's  Cursor property to the WaitCursor when you start the background operation, and then when the event fires to signal the worker's completed, change the cursor back.

Comment: What class does this code live in?  What is `this`?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnStartAsyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    backgroundworkerprocess.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backgroundworkerprocess_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do work
}
```

Then just simply change the Cursor back in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: Hi CollMinE ,Chris has provided the solution for my issue .So instead of using this code.            this.dispatcher.invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new action((delegate) {
            this.cursor = cursors.wait;
        })
    ); I have to write this one this.dispatcher.invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new action((delegate) {
            Window.GetWindow(this).Cursor = cursors.wait
        })
    );

Answer (score 0):

I dont think people understand you.

try this, sending it to Dispatcher:
Window.GetWindow(this).Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

Comment: Many Thanks Chris ,its now working as i desired .Ya you are right people do not understand my problem ,in the future i will be more elaborate and clear(if i got some issues)